# To Wrap a Loop - Python

Tags: python, loops, wrapper

If I want to call a function both in a single iteration and in a looping function, that reuses the same code, whats the proper way to create the two functions?

Here is an example single function `DoStuff` and 3 attempts to create a second way of calling it, in `__name__=="__main__"`.

```
import time

def DoStuff(txt):
    """Do it one time"""
    print(txt)

def LoopStuff(txt):
    """Function of a Function"""
    try:
        while True:
            if time.time() % 5 < 1:
                DoStuff(txt) 
                time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("You killed it.")
    except:
        print("Loop Failed.")
        
def Loop(function):
    """This one's broken"""
    try:
        while True:
            if time.time() % 5 < 1:
                function()
                time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("You killed it.")
    except:
        print("Loop Failed.")
        
def Looped(function):
    """Wrapper"""
    def wrap(*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            while True:
                if time.time() % 5 < 1:
                    function(*args, **kwargs) 
                    time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("You killed it.")
        except:
            print("Loop Failed.")
    return wrap
        
@Looped
def WrapStuff(txt):
    """Hows this work?"""
    DoStuff(txt)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    DoStuff("one time text")
    LoopStuff("Function fuction")
    Loop(DoStuff("what's your"))
    WrapStuff("conjunction?")
```

I was trying to create a loop that ran every min, regardless of execution time, but I have shortened it to 5 seconds here for troubleshooting. Maybe there's a better way to do this with a chron type behavior, but that's not really the question I'm asking here.

The 1st and 3rd attempt work but the 2nd exits with

```
  in <module> Loop(DoStuff("what's your"))
  in Loop function()
TypeError: 'NoneType' is not callable
```

Comment: You're not monitoring which functions should take arguments, and not passing in required arguments in at least one case. What error do you get and were?

Comment: Post the entire error in your question. Look carefully at the line that raises it.

Comment: Where is the asynchronous function?

Comment: It's the wrong word in python, since it implies an `async` somewhere. Every 5 seconds is just "every 5 seconds"

Comment: Still need to edit the error and traceback into your question

Comment: I understand that your main goal is not to fix the error, but how do you expect to determine which method works best if you don't fix it first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246953/discussion-between-alphy13-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 0):

I just went trial and error until I found this code that worked. It seems like this will let me use `Looped` in a wrapper function and in this single line style. If you have a better answer, please share.

It's just a cleaner way of what I was trying to accomplish with `WrapSuff`.

```
ShortWrap = Looped(DoStuff)

ShortWrap('my text')
```

I can see, in hindsight, that the second example `Loop(DoStuff("what's your"))` is just a failed half-step between the first and third example.